# Moving Maildir directory out of /home

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, dovecot, maildir

I have a computer with Ubuntu 13.04 with a local IMAP server that I use to share email over the LAN. I set this computer up to have an encrypted /home, however this therefore means that anyone logging into the server won't be able to view the IMAP folders unless the local user is also logged in. I want to therefore move the mail to `/var/mail/Maildir/%u`.

I have the following in my `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf`

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/Maildir/%u
```

And my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` has:

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

However when I log in locally with a mail client over IMAP, it recreates the `~/Maildir` directory instead of using `/var/mail/`. What am I missing?

**Edit:**

Here is my `postconf -n` after applying shutupsquare's answer:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = dovecot
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain, ubuntu
myhostname = host
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.1.0/24
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

**Edit 2:** my /var/log/mail.log contains the following:

```
May  4 02:10:01 servername postfix/local[469]: warning: connect #7 to subsystem private/dovecot: No such file or directory
May  4 02:10:11 servername postfix/local[469]: warning: connect #8 to subsystem private/dovecot: No such file or directory
May  4 02:10:21 servername postfix/local[469]: warning: connect #9 to subsystem private/dovecot: No such file or directory
May  4 02:10:31 servername postfix/local[469]: warning: connect #10 to subsystem private/dovecot: No such file or directory
May  4 02:10:41 servername postfix/local[469]: fatal: connect #11 to subsystem private/dovecot: No such file or directory
May  4 02:10:42 servername postfix/qmgr[30763]: warning: private/local socket: malformed response
May  4 02:10:42 servername postfix/qmgr[30763]: warning: transport local failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
May  4 02:10:42 servername postfix/master[30759]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/local pid 469 exit status 1
May  4 02:10:42 servername postfix/master[30759]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/local: bad command startup -- throttling
```

Answer (score 1):

in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

Remove:

`home_mailbox = Maildir/`

and add this line in:

`mailbox_transport = dovecot`

You should also have in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-lda.conf`

`lda_mailbox_autocreate = yes`

Comment: That didn't seem to work

Comment: See the edit, file name maybe different in Ubuntu mind they like to do stuff like that.

Comment: PS, `service restart dovecot && service restart postfix` after changing files.

Comment: Hmm tried that too and it still doesn't work. It's still trying to look under `~/Maildir` when I check for mail and recreating that directory when it doesn't exist

Comment: post the `/var/log/mail.log` when its looking up the mailbox, and turn dovecots logging on for mail.

Comment: Sounds like postfix is still trying to deliver mail to mailbox instead of dovecot.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's mail delivery though because I haven't actually tried to deliver any mails to it yet, just retrieve the ones that are currently there.

Comment: See updated question

Comment: Okay forget trying to get dovecot to deliver mail, set your main.cf `home_mailbox=/var/mail/Maildir/%u` that will get postfix to put the mail in the right place, next switch on mail debug for dovecot and lets see the output when you try and get mail.

Comment: Turns out the problem was that I had to edit the file `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/99-mail-stack-delivery.conf` instead of `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf`. Add that to your answer and I'll accept it.